# How can I get the average number of distinct users per day of the week?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get the average number of distinct customers and employees per day of the week (i.e., how many distinct customers call on an average Tuesday?) using SQLite.

Here is some example data. These dates are all Tuesdays, so in this case the average number of distinct customers for a Tuesday is 1 and the average number of distinct employees working is 3:

```
 id   starttime           customer  employee
 1    2019-01-01 12:00    1         1
 2    2019-01-01 12:00    1         2
 3    2019-01-01 12:00    1         3
 4    2019-01-08 12:00    2         1
 5    2019-01-08 12:00    2         2
 6    2019-01-08 12:00    2         3
 7    2019-01-15 12:00    3         1
 8    2019-01-15 12:00    3         2
 9    2019-01-15 12:00    3         3



select strftime('%w', starttime) as day_number,
count(distinct customer) / count(distinct starttime) as 
    avg_customer,
count(distinct employee) / count(distinct starttime) as 
    avg_employee
from logins
group by strftime('%w', starttime);
```

I tried the above code, which works for customer (output is 1) but not employee (output is 1, but should be 3), which I now realise is because I need to calculate a count for each date and then divide by the number of dates, rather than count distinct employees  across all dates and then divide by number of dates, but I am struggling to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the average number of distinct users per day of the week?

1. Get the number of distinct users per day.
2. Get the average per week.

The query:

```
select
  strftime('%w', day) as week,
  avg(customers) as avg_customer,
  avg(employees) as avg_employee
from
(
  select
    date(starttime) as day,
    count(distinct customer) as customers,
    count(distinct employee) as employees
  from logins
  group by date(starttime)
) days
group by strftime('%w', day)
order by strftime('%w', day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop both occurrences of

```
/ count(distinct starttime)
```

So you are left with a query that gives you the number of distinct customers and employees per day.

Then, nest that whole query inside another which simply averages those fields

```
Select AVG(distinct_customers), AVG(distinct_employees) from (your query)
```

It's a good rule of thumb when averaging anything not to do the division until the very last step, get everything added up first, then divide.